# Combining 'AND' and 'OR' Condition in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Back again needing more help with constructing my NSPredicates :(

```
Category
{
   name:string
   subs<-->>SubCategory
}

SubCategory
{
   name:string
   numbervalue:NSNumber
}
```

I would like to know how to create a predicate with **AND** and **OR**.

For example, I would like to return every Category with name == "category_name" that also has a subcategory with a numbervalue of "valueA" **OR** "valueB".

I've tried every possible combination of predicate constructors I could come up with but I just cant get it to work.

This is my best attempt so far.

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"(name== %@) AND (ANY subs.numbervalue==%@ OR ANY subs.numbervalue==%@)", @"aname", value1, value2];
```

**Edit 1**

Second attempt. The filtering on the 'numbervalue' is still not working.

```
NSNumber valueA=[NSNumber numberWithInt:20];
NSNumber valueA=[NSNumber numberWithInt:90];
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:valueA,valueB,nil];

predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name==%@)AND(ANY subs.numbervalue IN %@)",@"aname",arr];
```

**Edit 2**

I've tried filtering just by numberValue and have left the name out alltogether.

1) using this results in the entire set being returned even if only 1 item in the set has the value.

```
predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY subs.numbervalue IN %@)",arr];
```

2) Using this results in the same problem, every item in the set being returned even if only 1 of them matches.

```
predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((SUBQUERY(subs, $x, $x.numbervalue == %@ or $x.numbervalue == %@).@count > 0)", value1, value2];
```

Also using the simplest version results in the same problem.... I didnt notice this earlier.

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"(ANY subs.numbervalue==%@ ,valueA];
```

So I think I have my problem narrowed down.

Category is an Entity.
SubCategory is an Entity.

Category has a one to many relationship with SubCategory and is represented as an NSSet of SubCategory.

Each SubCategory has an attribute named numbervalue.

**Edit 3**

To test I have 2 Categorys.
Both Categories have 10 subs, each with a numbervalue of 1 -10;

Using this code both categories are returned along with all 10 subs for each.

Expected result is both categories returned , each with just 2 subs.

I've traced out all my objects and the data is correct. The problem is I cant return a category that has filtered subs.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[[DataSource sharedDataSource]managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate;
NSNumber *a=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
NSNumber *b=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2];
predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(subs,$x,$x.numbervalue==%@ or $x.numbervalue==%@).@count> 0)",a,b];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
[NSFetchedResultsContoller deleteCacheWithName:nil];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

   NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   abort();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `NSCompoundPredicate`? It should help you. Also try using `... AND (ANY subs.numberValue IN %@)", @"fooName", numArray`

Comment: use $x.numbervalue and not $numbervalue. Then try to set the cache to nil first and see the result.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted. Thanks for all your help. In the end I had to filter my category.subs in functions such as numberofrowsinsection. It's stinks of a hack but it seems to be working

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'll do the following using a `SUBQUERY`.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"(name == %@) AND (SUBQUERY(subs, $x, $x.numbervalue == %@ or $x.numbervalue == %@).@count > 0)", @"aname", value1, value2];
```

Try it and let me know.

Another solution could be to grab the whole collection `subs` and then filter the retrieved set with a predicate to check if elements match for `value1` or `value2`.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

If you follow **Eimantas** suggestion make to sure to create the right array:

```
NSNumber valueA = [NSNumber numberWithInt:20];
NSNumber valueB = [NSNumber numberWithInt:90];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:valueA, valueB, nil];
```

Comment: what seems to be happening is if a collection of subs has a number value of 90 for example but the rest are say 0, the entire collection of subs still gets returnd

Comment: Try to use only *(SUBQUERY(subs, $x, $x.numbervalue == %@ or $x.numbervalue == %@).@count > 0)* in the predicate and the filter the array with an additional predicate to find that name.

Comment: What result do you retrieve using only the SUBQUERY?

Comment: I updated my answer. No matter what I do every entry in each subs gets returned even if only 1 of them has the correct value.

Comment: @dubbeat This is quite strange. The *NSPredicate* is right. I tried it in one project and it works. Few suggestions if you use slqlite as support storage. First enable tracking sql operation with [debugging-core-data-on-the-iphone](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/11/debugging-core-data-on-the-iphone.html). Then try to explore your data inserted in the db. Two ways: load managed objects and print them with *NSLog* or explore your sqllite file directly. Maybe you could find something strange maybe because you created data in a wrong manner. This is only an assumption. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried the code relentlessly, I really don't know what is wrong. Are we talking about the same thing? I've updated my question to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 95):

Addition to @Stuart's answer, you can use NSCompoundPredicate for your OR & AND operations like this.

**Obj-C  - OR**

```
// OR Condition //

NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Obj-C  - AND**

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Swift - OR**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift - AND**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift 3 - OR**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

**Swift 3 - AND**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

Comment: Great! I wanted something exactly like that.

Answer (score 13):

For Swift, this is how you can do it:

**SWIFT 4.x - AND**

```
        let p0 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
```

**SWIFT 4.x - OR**

```
        let p0 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
```

**SWIFT 4.x - NOT**

```
        let p0 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(notPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
```

**Example**

This is an example from one of my codes, where I look for uid and sync:

```
        let p0 = NSPredicate(format: self.uid + " = '" + uid + "'")
        let p1 = NSPredicate(format: self.sync + " = %@", NSNumber(value: true as Bool))
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p0, p1])
```

Comment: My answer is downvoted as vandalism. It is a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: `NOT` would have a _single_ predicate. e.g.  See Foundation documentation for ['NSCompoundPredicate'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate) and ['init(notPredicateWithSubpredicate:)'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate/1409462-init).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an NSCompoundPredicate (note andPredicateWithSubpredicates does an AND but there are a few options to use, this should be much more efficient than doing 2 searches)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/andPredicateWithSubpredicates:)