# Combining "And" and "Or" on NSPredicates

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

I want to do something like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@ AND (position == %@ OR position == %@), name, position1, position2)
```

However, I've tried that and I keep getting serious Core Data application errors. I then tried using NSCompoundPredicate, but I can't combine "AND" and "OR"s there either.

I've read [Combining 'AND' and 'OR' Condition in NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317692/combining-and-and-or-condition-in-nspredicate) and it's different in that the questioner wanted an "OR" on a subcollection so the answer involves a subquery which I don't want.

How do I do this?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have your tried `"( name contains[cd] %@ )AND (position in %@)",name,[position1,position2])` ?

Comment: thanks, that was a better way than I was doing it!

Comment: Turns out I mistakenly thought the above wasn't working.  Before I was trying to add strings using traditional Swift interpolation via a for loop to an NSPredicate - which I suspect caused the Core Data errors.  Then I forgot that was the problem after trying things with NSCompoundPredicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment.  What you have posted should work.  It might help to post more of your code to identify the exact issue.

In hopes that it helps you catch your issue, I'll post a working sample with combined `AND` and `OR`:

```
let alice = Person(firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Smith", age: 24, position: "Up")
let bob = Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones", age: 27, position: "Left")
let charlie = Person(firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Smith", age: 33, position: "Right")
let quentin = Person(firstName: "Quentin", lastName: "Alberts", age: 31, position: "Down")
let people = [alice, bob, charlie, quentin]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[cd] %@ AND (position == %@ OR position == %@)", "e", "Up", "Down")
let filtered = (people as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)

print(filtered)

// prints [Alice Smith, Quentin Alberts]
```