# Obj-c - How can I check if NSString contains one OR the other?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I want to check if my NSString 'name' contains "Brittany" or "Bob", but the following code doesn't seem to do the trick?

**ViewController.m**

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@ OR name contains[cd] %@", @"Brittany", @"Bob"];
NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Any idea what this should look like instead? I can't seem to get the syntax right. The issue is that 'filtered' is not returning the arrays in which string name containing "Bob", just the ones in which name contains "Brittany".

**Here is what self.messages contains:**

```
 This is the messages data (
            {
            body = "Hi";
            endswaptime = "<null>";
            "first name" = Brittany;
            name = Brittany;
            nid = 1803;
            "node_title" = "Re:";
        },
            {
            body = "It is brittany";
            endswaptime = "<null>";
            "first name" = Brittany;
            name = Brittany;
            nid = 1804;
            "node_title" = "Re:";

        },
            {
            body = "Hellooo :)\n";
            endswaptime = "<null>";
            "first name" = Bob;
            name = "Bob";
            nid = 1805;
            "node_title" = "Re:";


        }
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried splitting the single predicate into two separate predicates and combining with NSCompoundPredicate?

Comment: I haven't - can you show me what that would look like? Help is appreciated!

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted? It looks correct. Of course a lot depends on what kind of data is actually in `self.messages`. Update your question with details about its contents.

Comment: @rmaddy See updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps splitting the predicate into two separate predicates and combining with `NSCompoundPredicate` will help?

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", @"Brittany"];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", @"Bob"];
NSCompoundPredicate *p = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: I'm thrown the error: "No known class method for selector 'orPredicateWithSubPredicates' on the third line of that block?

Comment: Apologies. It should be orPredicateWithSubpredicates. I typed method name off the top of my head.

Comment: @Brittany If this worked then your original code should have worked. Perhaps you had a typo somewhere.

Comment: Glad it worked! I agree with @rmaddy. The original code SHOULD work but I know I have ran into this sort of thing in the past and that is why I suggested it...

Answer (score -2):

I written in swift language. Try to convert into Objective c.
var str = ["Hello", "hel","hello"]

let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@","Hello")
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@","helo")
let predicatecompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
print(str.filter { predicatecompound.evaluate(with: $0) })

Reference:
[Combining 'AND' and 'OR' Condition in NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317692/combining-and-and-or-condition-in-nspredicate)